# event logs with geth fast sync

Tags: go-ethereum, events, fast-sync

> If I use --fast syncing, will the contract execution **Event logs** be
>   available?

I wish to setup a private node to make RPC request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I recall correctly, After the sync is completed and the node has switched back to block syncing, you should be able to retrieve event logs as you would a normal node